# HTML and SVG image annotation for QGIS image not displaying

Tags: qgis, html, annotation, svg

I have installed the HTML/SVG annotation plugin with an image on my desktop that I'd like to use as the guinea pig. In the course of testing the plugin I've tried both HTML and SVG image formats but neither have worked when it comes to actually getting the image to display.

For the SVG annotation the annotation box is blank and for the HTML one it just lists the path with a bunch of small purple rectangles below it and the file path to the image above.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What´s the Qgis version?

Comment: HTML hasn't got an image format, can you clarify what you mean by `I've tried both HTML and SVG image formats`